# Find path of pip installed package, when it is no longer located at that path

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I install a package locally using

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now, a user (unintentionally) moves or renames a parent folder containing the package.

How can I find the path where the package was installed?

I have tried

- `pip list`
- `pip freeze`
- `importlib.import_module(package_name)`
- `pkg_resources.get_distribution(package_name)`
- `importlib.util.find_spec(package_name)`

All of the above methods give the same output as if the package had never been installed.
I need to find the location that the package had originally during the `pipinstall`. I cannot change the installation procedure, it has to be purely posthoc.

Comment: Maybe this sounds stupid, but have you tried to install it in another place and look the path that the new installation makes? Should be similar to the original.

Comment: I think all of those approaches just scan your site-packages. I don't think there is any record kept somewhere of where packages have been installed. Create a virtual environment, install in there and see what the installed folder structure looks like

Comment: @FlyingTeller It has to be recorded somewhere in order for it to know where to find the package once I import it?

Comment: No, pip is associated with a specific python interpreter. Both know where the corresponding site-packages lies. Pip can put packages there and the python interpreter scans the same folder and can then resolve any `import` by matching it against stuff in your current working directory, the site-packages and whatever might lie on PYTHONPATH. to know which packages are installed, pip also just needs to look at `site-packages` to see which packages are installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FlyingTeller I started looking at the `site-packages`, and found an `.egg-link` file there that contains the path of where the package was installed originally. This can be checked from `Python` as follows:

```
import site
for site_path in site.getsitepackages():
    egg_path = os.path.join(site_path, package_name + ".egg-link")
    if os.path.exists(egg_path):
        with open(egg_path, "r") as f:
            print(f"I tried looking in the following folder, but could not find the {package_name} package there:")
            print(f.read())
```